# App crashes on only iPhone 5 when adding GMSMarker to the map: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, google-maps-sdk-ios, iphone-5

The app I'm working on plots a lot of GMSMarkers on a google map. It works perfectly fine in all other devices, except iPhone 5. I have subclassed GMSMarker and set an object id to the subclass. This is done so that I can add the markers to an NSSet and ensure there are only distinct markers that are plotted and no duplicates. The subclass is:

```
@implementation BYOMarker
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    BYOMarker *otherMarker = (BYOMarker *)object;
    if (self.objectID.intValue == otherMarker.objectID.intValue) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
-(NSUInteger)hash
{
    return  [self.objectID hash];
}
@end
```

The .h file

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface BYOMarker : GMSMarker
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSNumber  *objectID;
@end
```

The app is crashing at the return of the hash function with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. I enabled Zombie objects and tried to print po marker.objectID when I'm setting the map object for the marker and I get the following error:

```
*** -[CFNumber respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x80416470
0x80416470
```

Any Help?! TIA

Comment: use strong rather than assign for objectID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a memory management problem with your `objectID` property. Don't use `assign` for object pointer properties. Use `strong`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *objectID;
```

Comment: How did I miss that! Thanks. Any idea why this is not handled only in iPhone 5? No other device led me to this mistake.